# Orthonormal vectors of $\left(-\frac{3+i}{2}, 1\right)$ and $\left(\frac{3+i}{5}, 1\right)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, orthonormal

> What is the orthonormal basis of $a = \left(-\frac{3+i}{2}, 1\right)$ and $b = \left(\frac{3+i}{5}, 1\right)$?

What I did so far:

Let $A = 2a$ (for simplicity). Note that $A^TA = 12+6i$.

Now $B = b - [(A^T.b)/((A^T).A)]A = (3/5+i/5, 1) - [2/5-i6/5]/12+6i](-3-i, 2) = \cdots$

And here I am lost with my calculations...

Help, please?

Comment: The question does not make sense: "orthonormal basis" is a concept for inner product spaces.

Comment: Maybe you are requested to orthonormalize the vectors?

Comment: Is there more to this question? $a$ and $b$ are linearly independent, so the standard basis seems like a perfectly good answer to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to use the Gram Schmidt orthonormalization method to construct two orthonormal vectors, given vectors $a$ and $b$. The inner product of complex vectors $v,w$ is *not* defined as $v^T\cdot w$, but as$^1$ $\overline{v^T}\cdot w$, i.e. you also need to take the complex conjugate of the first component. (Or depending on the book you use, conjugate the second component.)
On [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Complex_vectors) you can see how it is defined.

$a$ and $b$ are already orthogonal (calculate their inner product!), so $A=2a$ does not add simplicity.
Now you only need to normalize $a$ and $b$.

The norm of $a$ is the square root of the inner product $\langle a,a\rangle$, and:

$\langle a,a\rangle = -\frac{3+i}{2}\cdot-\frac{3-i}{2} + 1\cdot 1 = \frac{10}{4}+1=\frac{7}{2}$, so your first vector is normalized if you divide it by $\sqrt{7/2}$.

I think you can do the other inner product yourself, now you know the correct definition of the standard inner product :)

---

$1$: Actually, the transposing of a vector is not really the standard general way to define the inner product, but as you were already using it, I decided to just roll with it instead of touching a running machine.